# c#,Textbox not working while taking web respose

Tags: c#, winforms, http, textbox

I am using the following function to get response of a url from web. when i place the response in message box it displays properly.when i put it in text box the programme gets stuck on that statement and doesn't move.why is it happening,as i am feeding the string(`response_message`) to textbox.

```
void message_send(int j)
{
    int y = 0;

        if (CONTACT_NO[j] != "")
        {

        string Message = "hello";   



        string url = "some url not mentioned here ";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
              request.Timeout = 30000;
              using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
              {
                  byte[] bytes = ReadFully(response.GetResponseStream());
            response_message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            // error_logs(str);
            MessageBox.Show(response_message);
           textBox2.Text = response_message;
              }
        //textBox3.Text = response_message;

    }
        else
        {
           messagebox.show("some message");

        }
```

Comment: Do you have an handler for the TextChanged event ?

Comment: how many char does "response_message" have? Textbox usually has 250 limit on there char.

Comment: @Steve no text handler i just simply printing the string in textbox.

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte i even put manual message to it ,it doesn't show.even tried in my another project where i am taking web response still it doesn't display anything and keep on struck there.

Comment: try this.

textBox2.Text = response_message.toString();

or

textBox2.Text = convert.tostring(response_message);

Comment: Is this executing in a separate thread? If it does, you need to access the TextBox in a thread safe way! Do you get any exception?

Comment: Try assigning the value of `response_message` a local variable. Assign `TextBox2.Text` to use that variable after your using

Comment: Where do you use `message_send()` - is it in a thread other than UI? If so, then the answer is easy.

Comment: @pitersmx i am using it in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)` function

Comment: So as @NikolaDavidovic said, you need to make call to TextBox thread-safe. There are numerous ways to achieve that, read here for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @pitersmx i used one of the method and resolved the issue ,thankyou.it was definately the issue of thread safe call as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're multithreading your update to your textbox, you need to be aware that your worker thread can't update the textbox because the textbox wasn't created on the worker thread.

To update the textbox in a thread safe way, I'd recommend the easiest way of invoking:

```
TextBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { TextBox2.Text = response_message });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using my this function in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)` function.which i guess is separate thread.due to which i wasn't able to access `textbox1`.hence i used the following method to access it.

```
 private void SetText1(string text)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText1);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.textBox2.Text = text;
            }

        }
```

Mistake that i was doing i wasn't using the `try catch` method to check for the exception.which helps me in understanding my issue.